# How to set checked property to a custom styled TListBox?

Tags: delphi, listbox, styles, firemonkey

I have a custom `style` for a `TListBox` in `Delphi`, where I can simply change a `Text` attribute like

```
lb_item.StylesData['location'] := 'New Text for Style';
```

What if I have a `TCheckBox` on it, how can I attribute `isChecked` property to `true` or `false`?

I thought it would be something that looks like

```
lb_item.StylesData['checkitem'] := TCheckBox.isChecked;
```

or maybe even

```
lb_item.StylesData['checkitem.isChecked'] := true;
```

but I can't find anything.

Any ideas on how to set a property to a custom styled `TListBox`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ListBox1.ListItems[0].IsChecked := true;`